# Setting up squid proxy on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I have an Ubuntu machine, which has its IP white listed to access a certain URL. I want to visit this URL from my local machine, using the server as proxy. I installed squid on the server, but I can't figure out how to configure it.
What I'd like is that I set my firefox to use the server as proxy, so that I can directly access the website.
How should I setup Squid for this?
Thanks

Comment: You don't need to do anything to Squid - just go with the default package install then configure your browser to use the server as a proxy - what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Look onto this step by step tuto [server world](http://server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_11.04&p=squid). If you're not using ubuntu 11.04, you can choose your os in the other os menu.

Hope this will help